# Are there any Business benefits of converting XHTML1.0/HTML4 desktop website into HTML5 for now?

Tags: html, seo

Are there any Business benefits of converting XHTML1.0/HTML4 website into HTML5? I mean using HTML5 semantics tags wherever possible.

One client asked me that "If he spent money to re-factor his e-commerce website to HTML5 , will it add any benefit to his e-commerce business.

He showed me this link http://www.seroundtable.com/google-html5-14912.html which shows SEO will not increase (at least for now). and He still has good number of users from IE6. and he don't want to compromise on performance too for IE users just to use HTML5.

He has different website for mobile and desktop and don't want responsive design. and even on mobile website he wants maximum compatibility with devices so I'm not using HTML5 either on his mobile site too.

Should we skip the re factoring idea for now or there are some real benefits which can be beneficial for website and it's users by using HTML5?

Comment: Unless there are any HTML5 features they want to incorporate really badly, I would say there's no benefit to business as such, especially since they want to continue support for older versions of IE. But then that's my opinion. :)

Comment: Your question is very broad. Do an analysis to figure this out... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_area_%28CMMI%29#Decision_Analysis_and_Resolution_.28DAR.29.

Answer (score 4):

### HTML5 is Very Broad

**HTML5** is not only markup. It is a set of **unrelated features**. You can have a quick look of this by going to the [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/) website.

Why would you want HTML5? Again I invite you to the same site: [HTML5 Rocks (Why HTML5 Rocks?)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/why).

### What About Compatibility?

Compatibility is no longer an issue. There are tools out there on the World Wide Web that have been created by web designers and developers that were tired of this problem.

You can now create sites that can have a nice fallout if they do not support certain features and use alternatives. You can also use techniques such as [responsive design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) with [media queries](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) to make one site instead of several for the many different devices out there.

Note that IE6 is [officially dead](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/01/03/microsoft_ie6_death/) from Microsoft's perspective.

- [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) - HTML/CSS/JS template
- [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) - "Customisable CSS file that makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards"
- [HTML5 Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) - JS workaround to enable HTML5 elements in IE
- [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) - JS library for feature detection
- [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) - JS library for media query support in IE
- [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) - JS library that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes in IE

### Lets Get Down to Business!

At this point, you are probably telling yourself where is he getting to? Well it all turns down to money right?

HTML5 will [not really increase your ranking](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-seo/) in search engines. At best it can help categorize your content more properly. What HTML5 will do is give web creators the tools necessary to innovate.

HTML5 brings the possibility to make websites more engaging than ever. Interactivity is key to making users have an experience that they will remember and make them come back for more. HTML5 is revolutionizing the way content is created, developed and delivered.

Why not have a look at your client's source code and compare it with competitors. Are they using HTML5? If they are using it, then check out how they are doing it. And if they are not using HTML5, then why not be the first? After all, HTML4 and XHTML are behind us (1999-2000). It is inevitable that the update to HTML5 will happen.

Comment: I already know that. my question is different.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how the current website looks. I'm more likely to buy something from a nicer looking website because it looks more reputable, but could that nice design possibly be done in HTML 4 and increase compatibility. Really, if it looks good, then it doesn't matter either way. People are coming to buy something easily, and partially be impressed, rather than wondering what the technology is, and if the buttons give a sound when you click on them.

*Smooth transitions like fades or swipes through pages often look really professional and good though, like an iPhone (or whatever) app, but again this maybe could be done through AJAX and Javascript.*

Answer (score 1):

Here is one key thing to remember about HTML5: "for most practical purpose, it's not all-or-nothing". You can still have a site that is HTML4/XHTML1.0 and embed a couple feature or two from HTML 5, e.g. microformat, video tag, HTML5 forms, CSS3, etc. The downside is that your page may not fully validate with either DOCTYPE, but if you're fine with that then browsers, users, and search engine would still be able to chug through the site just fine.

The most important thing to remember is that older browsers (i.e. IE) ignore your HTML5 tag, so you can't use them for CSS hooks (unless you use a Javascript shim); and features like video tag wouldn't show on older browsers, so you might want to use the javascript-/flash-based shims for those.

Comment: I have a correction for your second paragraph: most browsers, when encountering an element they don't recognize, will treat it as a generic inline-level element. However, they'll still respect any CSS rules you apply to it, so it's not that big of an issue. Internet Explorer is the exception rather than the rule; it will act as if the unknown element doesn't exist and dump its contents into the parent element. So yes, shims are sometimes necessary, but only for older versions of Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. In my company we just had some great workshops about SEO by a company that is specialised on SEO optimizations and are working together with google. they actually recommended us to be as semantic as possible and use the attributes for html elements correctly...

Also they enrouraged us to implement [HTML5 Microdata](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/microdata.html) as the Google Crawler is already using it and therefore you can give more precise information about your page.

Comment: See this video from google http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fL_GZwoC2uQ they even didn't have problem with table based sites

Comment: interesting video... I think in general you could say that it is useful in technical / semantic sense but for most common practices not necessarily needed... should maybe considered when it is worked on such pages anyway...